# react native navigation when include a view in another view

Tags: react-native, navigation

I have a problem with navigating between screens with react native. here is my stack navigator

```
Login: {
    screen: Login
},
Home: {
    screen: Home,
    nestedScreen: LoginForm,
},
LoginForm: {
    screen: LoginForm
},
```

and my login page is like this

```
<View style={styles.formContainer}>
            <LoginForm />
        </View>
```

Now how can I use navigator from the login form file. I used but it resulted in "Malformed call from JS: field sizes are different"

Comment: just add your whole code so anyone can get it easily and/or add expo snack.

Comment: @ParasKorat I found the solution, I need to pass the navigation param to LoginForm

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below code:

```
Login: {
            screen: LoginScreen,
        },
        SetPassword: {
            screen: SetPasswordScreen,
        },

        mainFlow: {
            screen: TabNavigator(
                {
                    overviewFlow: {
                        screen: StackNavigator(
                            {
                                Overview: {
                                    screen: OverviewScreen,
                                },
                                DietitianInfo: {
                                    screen: DietitianInfoScreen,
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                headerMode: 'none',
                            }
                        )
                    },
                    Goals: {
                        screen: GoalsScreen,
                    },
                    diaryFlow: {
                        screen: StackNavigator(
                            {
                                DiaryOverview: {
                                    screen: DiaryOverviewScreen,
                                },
                                DiaryEntry: {
                                    screen: DiaryEntryScreen,
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                headerMode: 'none',
                            }
                        )
                    },

                    Notes: {
                        screen: NotesScreen,
                    },
                },
                {
                    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
                    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                        // ...                         
                    }),
                    tabBarOptions: {
                       // ...
                    },
                }
            )
        }
    },
```